# Open file location in GUI using keyboard only

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I know about the

```
[ctrl] + [alt] + t

[ctrl] + f

[alt] + f1
```

shortcuts to bring up the standard system browsing tools, and I use them often. I am not satisfied with them (except the terminal...of course).

My question is: is there an equivalent to the Window's shortcut

```
[windows-key] + e
```

that brings up the "Computer" window? Having access to the GUI based file browser is nice, especially when I am literally browsing for a file in an unknown location.

```
pwd
ls
cd
```

gets a little old when you're not 100% sure what you're looking for.

Please answer the question in a manner that I could add your tip to the keyboard shortcut menu, which is found by running

```
gnome-keybinding-properties
```

at the command line on debian-type distributions. If you've got something I could grab from synaptic, I'd appreciate that as well.

Thanks.

p.s. I hate the mouse. Please don't tell me to double click the Computer icon on the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your file manager is nautilus since you mentioned gnome.
can you add custom keyboard shotcut?  if yes, add this command to a custom shortcut.

```
nautilus computer:///
```

btw
if you really hate mouse, you would like to try ranger. http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/ranger

Comment: This looks about right. If it works, I'll definitely give you best answer for the `[windows-key] + e` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Into `gnome-keybinding-properties`, their is a `home directory` shortcut. Type

```
[your_shortcut_for_home_directory], <alt> + <up>, <alt> + <up>
```

(very quickly).

Comment: `nautilus .` is a pretty solution if you spend most of your time into a terminal :D